# How to return dynamic results sets from a Db2 anonymous block via JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I'm looking at the [Db2 LUW feature "returning result sets from SQL"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedures-returning-result-sets-from-sql), which seems to work in a similar fashion to what's possible in MySQL, SQL Server by running a simple `SELECT` from any procedural logic, or in Oracle by using `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`. The following anonymous block seems to be valid:

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE i < 10 DO
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE cur CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR SELECT i FROM sysibm.dual;
      OPEN cur;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Yet, it produces this warning, and no results are being fetched by e.g. DBeaver:

> Procedure "BEGIN...END" returned "9" query result sets, which exceeds the defined limit "0".. SQLCODE=464, SQLSTATE=0100E, DRIVER=4.26.14

If this were a procedure, I'd have to declare:

> DYNAMIC RESULT SETS n

But how can I declare this in an anonymous block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return result sets if not from a procedure

See [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-declare-cursor)

> WITH RETURN
> Specifies that the result table of the cursor is intended to be used as a result set that will be returned from a procedure. WITH
> RETURN is relevant only if the DECLARE CURSOR statement is contained
> with the source code for a procedure. In other cases, the precompiler
> might accept the clause, but it has no effect.

I understand that it may just be an example, but procedural statements are not needed to return integers from 1 to  10, the following query also does :

```
with loop(k) as (
  values 1
  union all select k+1 from loop where k < 10
)
select * from loop order by k
```

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It works on my 11.1 at least.

```
    String str = 
        "begin"
    + "  declare l_c CURSOR; "
    + "  set l_c = cursor with hold for select empno from employee; "
    + "  open l_c; "
    + "  set ? = l_c; "
    + "end";
    CallableStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try 
    {
        st = con.prepareCall(str);
        st.registerOutParameter (1, com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Types.CURSOR); 
        st.execute(); 
        rs = (java.sql.ResultSet) st.getObject(1);
        if (rs != null)
        {
          while (rs.next()) 
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
          rs.close();           
        }
    } ...
```